# Fortran 2D array initialization

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

The following program compiles with ifort (version 12) but not with GFortran (up to version 4.8):

```
PROGRAM TEST
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL,DIMENSION(2,2)::X=(/1,2,3,4/)

WRITE(*,*) X

END PROGRAM TEST
```

GFortran gives the error

```
REAL,DIMENSION(2,2)::X=(/1,2,3,4/)  
                       1  
Error: Incompatible ranks 2 and 1 in assignment at (1)
```

Ifort compiles the program and gives the expected output. Is this a bug in GFortran or does intel fortran simply allow non-standard array initialization?

Comment: Does it compile with a `RESHAPE()` statement in the initialization.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Re-write array declaration line as:

```
REAL,DIMENSION(2,2) :: X = RESHAPE([1,2,3,4],[2,2])
```

The reason ifort compiled it the other way is non-standard implementation. This is a way you can initialize arrays of rank higher than 1.

Comment: Beat me to it. See also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3708370/623518. Strangely I cannot get ifort to complain about the OP's array initialisation, even with all the warning, error and standard version flags I can think of, even though I'm sure it is non-standard. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm...not sure. ifort is usually more strict than pgf90 when taking shortcuts, at least with the stuff I do, so I was a little surprised ifort allowed this. I have very little experience with gfortran though.

Comment: Thank you all. I knew already about the RESHAPE keyword. Was really just interested if ifort was accepting non-standard code. Seems that the answer is yes.