# How to allocate memory for a matrix?

Tags: memory-management, matrix, fortran

I want to allocate memory for a matrix filled with double elements with Fortran 90, below is the corresponding C code:

```
int dim = 1024;
double *M = (double *)malloc(dim*dim*sizeof(double));
```

I wrote the code below but I could not access `M(i)` with `i>=100`:

```
program matrix
INTEGER :: i,d
CHARACTER(len=32) :: arg
REAL*8 M(*)
POINTER(ptr_M, M)

d=0
if(iargc() == 1) then
    call getarg(1, arg)
    read(arg, '(I10)') d
end if
print '("Dimension=", i6)', d

!allocate and init matrix
ptr_M = malloc(d*d*8)
do i=1,d*d
    M(i) = i
end do

print '("M(i)=", f7.4)', M(100)
call free(ptr_M)

end program matrix
```

what's wrong?

---

Thanks to all, here is my final solution:

```
program matrix
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, ALLOCATABLE :: M(:,:)
INTEGER :: i, j, d
CHARACTER(len=32) :: arg

!specify dimension with programm parameter
if(iargc() == 1) then
    call getarg(1, arg)
    read(arg, '(I10)') d
end if

!create and init matrix
ALLOCATE (M(d, d))
do i=1,d
    do j=1,d
        M(i, j) = (i - 1)*d+j
        write (*,*) "M(",i,",",j,")=",M(i, j)
    end do
end do
DEALLOCATE (M)

end program matrix
```

Comment: This may be covered by [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708307/how-to-initialize-two-dimensional-arrays-in-fortran)

Comment: Do you really need cray pointers?

Comment: Also, use the tag `fortran`. There is no sense in using tag `fortran90`, as your code definitely does not conform to this standard. (not even close)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an ALLOCATABLE array, you can allocate a matrix with 100 rows and 200 columns as follows:

```
program xalloc
real, allocatable :: x(:,:)
allocate(x(100,200))
end program xalloc
```