# How to construct a matrix containing 9 smaller matrix

Tags: matrix, fortran

I have nine matrices whose dimension as (N by N)
`A1(i,j),A2(i,j),A3(i,j),A4(i,j),A5(i,j),A6(i,j),A7(i,j),A8(i,j),A9(i,j)`

Then I want to construct a larger matrix (3N by 3N) including these nine matrices as:

```
A = [A1 A2 A3
     A4 A5 A6
     A7 A8 A9]
```

In fortran, can I use the command line as

```
do i=1,FN
   do j=1,FML
      A(i,j) = [A1(i,j),A2(i,j),A3(i,j);A4(i,j),A5(i,j),A6(i,j);A7(i,j),A8(i,j),A9(i,j)]
   end do
end do
```

Comment: You want to construct in what language? The command line at the and doesn't make much sense. What does it mean that you can use that command line?

Comment: You can always use subarrays as `A(1:3,1:3) = A1` if that is what you want.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks, sir.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for fun, you can also make the large A matrix by using do-loops as

```
do i = 1, N
    A( i,       : ) = [ A1( i,: ), A2( i,: ), A3( i,: ) ]
    A( i + N,   : ) = [ A4( i,: ), A5( i,: ), A6( i,: ) ]
    A( i + N*2, : ) = [ A7( i,: ), A8( i,: ), A9( i,: ) ]
enddo
```

which fills the A matrix in row-major way and so the small matrices also appear in that way. If really really necessary, this could also be written as one-liner as

```
A = transpose( reshape(  &
        [ ( [ A1( i,: ), A2( i,: ), A3( i,: ) ], i=1,N ), &
          ( [ A4( i,: ), A5( i,: ), A6( i,: ) ], i=1,N ), &
          ( [ A7( i,: ), A8( i,: ), A9( i,: ) ], i=1,N ) ], [N*3, N*3] ))
```

which turns out to be the transpose of the second array constructor in the @francescalus answer (in one-liner form)

```
A = reshape(  &
        [ ( [ A1( :,i ), A4( :,i ), A7( :,i ) ], i=1,N ), &
          ( [ A2( :,i ), A5( :,i ), A8( :,i ) ], i=1,N ), &
          ( [ A3( :,i ), A6( :,i ), A9( :,i ) ], i=1,N ) ], [N*3, N*3] )
```

---

To go one-step further, we may define `hcat` and `vcat` routines as in other languages (note here that explicit interface is necessary):

```
function hcat( A, B, C ) result( X )
    integer, dimension(:,:) :: A, B, C
    integer :: X( size(A,1), size(A,2)+size(B,2)+size(C,2) )

    X = reshape( [ A, B, C ], shape( X ) )
endfunction

function vcat( A, B, C ) result( X )
    integer, dimension(:,:) :: A, B, C
    integer :: X( size(A,1)+size(B,1)+size(C,1), size(A,2) )

    X = transpose( reshape( &
            [ transpose(A), transpose(B), transpose(C) ], &
            [ size(X,2), size(X,1) ] ) )
endfunction
```

then we can write

```
A = vcat( hcat( A1, A2, A3 ), hcat( A4, A5, A6 ), hcat( A7, A8, A9 ) )
```

which is somewhat more similar to the desired form in the question:

```
A = [ A1 A2 A3 ; A4 A5 A6 ; A7 A8 A9 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Although Fortran is helpful when it comes to array manipulation, creation of block matrices isn't as elegant as you want from your examples (and would come from certain other languages).

It's possible to use an array constructors to create your desired matrix, much as would be done with [scalar elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3708307).  That is, `RESHAPE([A1, A2, A3, ..., A9],[3*N,3*N])` will give you a `3*N`x`3*N` matrix. It's just that it won't be the one you want.

As with the other question/answers the array constructor `[...]` considers the array element order to create a rank-1 array of length `9*N**2`, which is then `reshape`d to a square matrix.  Where those other examples used scalar elements here you have arrays for the data in the constructor.  The elements of the constructor are themselves taken in array element order, which would be equivalent to

```
[A1(1,1), A1(2,1), ..., A1(1,2), A1(2,2), ..., A2(1,1), ... ]
```

which is unwanted.

So, a constructor would be something like

```
[A1(:,1), A4(:,1), A7(:,1), A1(:,2), ..., A6(:,3), A9(:,3)]
```

which works, but is unwieldy.

There may be other tricks to get something more "elegant" into the constructor, but as Vladimir F comments, it may be much nicer to just do direct assignment to the various blocks:

```
A(1:N,1:N) = A1
A(1:N,N+1:2*N) = A2
A(1:N,2*N+1:3*N) = A3
A(N+1:2*N,1:N) = A4
....
```

Comment: If you can make the first set a `9xnxn` matrix, then at least you can do that assignment in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
program reshape_test
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: N = 2
   integer, dimension(N,N) :: A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9
   character(20) fmt
   integer A(3*N,3*N)
   A1 = reshape([11,21,12,22],[N,N])
   A2 = reshape([13,23,14,24],[N,N])
   A3 = reshape([15,25,16,26],[N,N])
   A4 = reshape([31,41,32,42],[N,N])
   A5 = reshape([33,43,34,44],[N,N])
   A6 = reshape([35,45,36,46],[N,N])
   A7 = reshape([51,61,52,62],[N,N])
   A8 = reshape([53,63,54,64],[N,N])
   A9 = reshape([55,65,56,66],[N,N])
   write(fmt,'(*(g0))') '(a/',N,'(i2:1x))'
   write(*,fmt) 'A1 = ',transpose(A1)
   write(*,fmt) 'A2 = ',transpose(A2)
   write(*,fmt) 'A3 = ',transpose(A3)
   write(*,fmt) 'A4 = ',transpose(A4)
   write(*,fmt) 'A5 = ',transpose(A5)
   write(*,fmt) 'A6 = ',transpose(A6)
   write(*,fmt) 'A7 = ',transpose(A7)
   write(*,fmt) 'A8 = ',transpose(A8)
   write(*,fmt) 'A9 = ',transpose(A9)
   A = reshape([reshape([A1,A4,A7,A2,A5,A8,A3,A6,A9],[N,3,N,3],order=[1,3,2,4])],[3*N,3*N])
   write(fmt,'(*(g0))') '(a/',3*N,'(i2:1x))'
   write(*,fmt) 'A = ',transpose(A)
end program reshape_test
```

Too long by 4774 characters

```
! [Sigh]
program reshape_test
!
! PROBLEM: Insert J*K M X N matrices AI(I)%A into a J X K block matrix A.
! The blocks AI(I)%A may be input in column-major or row-major order, and
! may be transposed or direct.
!
! SOLUTION: The RESHAPE intrinsic may perform the required pivot
! operation, if the command is designed carefully.
! Step 1: Work out the strides the inputs in array element order will
! be seen in output matrix.
! Step 2: The first 3 extents of the intermediate array may then be
! obtained by sorting the strides ascending and taking the ratios
! between adjacent strides. The 4th extent is such as to match the
! size of the intermediate array with the inputs.
! Step 3: The order of the indices is set so that each index steps
! through the inputs at its proper stride.
!
! EXAMPLE: In the column-major, direct case the second element of the
! inputs will be AI(1)%A(2,1) which should map to A(2,1) in the output,
! at offset of 1 from A(1,1), thus the first stride is 1.
! The second level block will be AI(1)%A(:,2) which should map to
! A(1:M,2) in the output, at offset of M*J from A(1:M,1), thus the
! second stride is M*J.
! The third level block will be AI(K+1)%A which should map to
! A(M+1:2*M,1:N), at offset M from A(1:M,1:N), so the third stride
! is M.
! The fourth level block is AI(2:K*(J-1)+2:K)%A which should map to
! A(1:M*J,N+1:2*N) at offset of M*N*J from A(1:M*J,1:N), so the fourth
! stride is M*N*J.
! Now strides = [1,M*J,M,M*N*J]
! Sort ascending: [1,M,M*J,M*N*J]
! Take ratios: [M,J,N]
! (M*N)*(J*K)/(M*J*N) = K, so SHAPE = [M,J,N,K].
! The first stride is 1, and that is stride take by the first index.
! The second stride is M*J, taken by the third index.
! The third stride is M, taken by the second index.
! The fourth stride is M*N*J, taken by the fourth index of the
! intermediate array. Hence ORDER = [1,3,2,4]
! Finally, to specify the input blocks in column major order such
! that they look read as row ajor in the output as specified,
! SOURCE = [((AI(IJ*(K-1)+IK)%A,IJ=1,J),IK=1,K)]
! Now that the elements of A are in the right order, a second RESHAPE
! casts the collection into the desired shape.
!
! EXERCISE: Permuting the elements of an array in bit-reversed order is
! another class of pivot operation. Write a RESHAPE invocation that
! performs this pivot operation. What are its limitations?
!
   implicit none
   integer M,N ! Each A_I is an M X N matrix
   integer J,K ! A is a J X K block matrix
   type A_type
      character(:), allocatable :: A(:,:) ! A block!
   end type A_type
   type(A_type), allocatable :: AI(:) ! Input blocks
   character(:), allocatable :: A(:,:) ! Output block matrix
   character(20) test_string ! To find max length of index
   integer LI ! Max length of block index
   integer LM ! Max length of row index
   integer LN ! Max length of column index
   integer I ! Block index
   integer IM ! Row of A(I)%A
   integer IN ! Column of A(I)%A
   character(40) fmt ! Variable FORMAT
   integer IJ ! Row of A
   integer IK ! Column of A

! Define problem dimensions
   M = 2
   N = 2
   J = 3
   K = 3
! Get max index lengths
   write(test_string,'(i0)') J*K
   LI = len_trim(test_string)
   write(test_string,'(i0)') M
   LM = len_trim(test_string)
   write(test_string,'(i0)') N
   LN = len_trim(test_string)
! Create FORMAT for array element label
   write(fmt,'(4(a,i0))') "('A',i0.",LI,",'(',i",LM,",',',i",LN,",')')"
! Create blocks
   allocate(AI(J*K))
   do I = 1, J*K
      allocate(character(4+LI+LM+LN)::AI(I)%A(M,N))
      do IM = 1,M
         do IN = 1,N
            write(AI(I)%A(IM,IN),fmt) I,IM,IN
         end do
      end do
   end do
! Solve the 4 versions
   write(*,'(a)') 'Column-major, direct'
   write(*,'(a)') 'Input order'
   allocate(character(4+LI+LM+LN)::A(J*M,K*N))
   write(fmt,'(3(a,i0))') "(",J*K,"('A',i0.",LI,":','))"
   write(*,fmt) ((K*(IJ-1)+IK,IJ=1,J),IK=1,K)
   A = reshape([reshape([((AI(K*(IJ-1)+IK)%A,IJ=1,J),IK=1,K)],[M,J,N,K],order=[1,3,2,4])],[M*J,N*K])
   write(fmt,'(3(a,i0))') '(',N*K,'(a',len(A),':1x))'
   write(*,fmt) transpose(A)
   deallocate(A)
   write(*,'()')
   write(*,'(a)') 'Row-major, direct'
   write(*,'(a)') 'Input order'
   allocate(character(4+LI+LM+LN)::A(J*M,K*N))
   write(fmt,'(3(a,i0))') "(",J*K,"('A',i0.",LI,":','))"
   write(*,fmt) (I,I=1,J*K)
   A = reshape([reshape([(AI(I)%A,I=1,J*K)],[M,J,N,K],order=[1,3,4,2])],[M*J,N*K])
   write(fmt,'(3(a,i0))') '(',N*K,'(a',len(A),':1x))'
   write(*,fmt) transpose(A)
   deallocate(A)
   write(*,'()')
   write(*,'(a)') 'Column-major, transposed'
   write(*,'(a)') 'Input order'
   allocate(character(4+LI+LM+LN)::A(J*N,K*M))
   write(fmt,'(3(a,i0))') "(",J*K,"('A',i0.",LI,":','))"
   write(*,fmt) ((K*(IJ-1)+IK,IJ=1,J),IK=1,K)
   A = reshape([reshape([((AI(K*(IJ-1)+IK)%A,IJ=1,J),IK=1,K)],[N,J,M,K],order=[3,1,2,4])],[N*J,M*K])
   write(fmt,'(3(a,i0))') '(',M*K,'(a',len(A),':1x))'
   write(*,fmt) transpose(A)
   deallocate(A)
   write(*,'()')
   write(*,'(a)') 'Row-major, transposed'
   write(*,'(a)') 'Input order'
   allocate(character(4+LI+LM+LN)::A(J*M,K*N))
   write(fmt,'(3(a,i0))') "(",J*K,"('A',i0.",LI,":','))"
   write(*,fmt) (I,I=1,J*K)
   A = reshape([reshape([(AI(I)%A,I=1,J*K)],[N,J,M,K],order=[3,1,4,2])],[N*J,M*K])
   write(fmt,'(3(a,i0))') '(',M*K,'(a',len(A),':1x))'
   write(*,fmt) transpose(A)
   deallocate(A)
end program reshape_test
```

Comment: please provide some description for your solution

Comment: Don't be surprised, if you get downvotes http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276774/how-to-deal-with-post-containing-only-code