# Error when using the function "transpose" in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I know that "transpose" in Fortran is an operator which flips a matrix over its diagonal. However, in the code below, I met an error and did not know why.

The code is:

```
program main
  implicit none
  real(8)::a(3,2),b(2,1)

  a=reshape((/1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0/),(/3,2/))
  b=reshape((/1.0,2.0/),(/2,1/))
  write(*,*)a(1,1:2)

  !Next sentence throw an error
  a(1,1:2)=transpose(b)
end program
```

The error is:

error #6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform.   [A]

I think "a(1,1:2)" is one line and two columns, which is the same as "transpose(b)", why the compiler told me that "the shape do not conform"?

Comment: Should have searched first. I see I even have a deleted answer under the duplicate.

Comment: Didn't even wait long enough to note that `real(8)` is ugly and not portable.

Comment: Sorry because I just searched "Error transpose Fortran ", and didn't find the solution. Afterwards I will try some other key words such as error displays.

Comment: About the real(8) problem, I found this: [Fortran 90 kind parameter
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter). I will use "selected_real_kind" in the future. Thanks!

Comment: You are wrong, a(1,1:2) is not a 2D array (which you call a matrix), it is a 1D array.

Bu using a(1,.. you are selecting a definite "row" in the "matrix" from which you take a "row vector" 1:2).

You must use

a(1:1,1:2)

Comment: Thx. I have seen your answer below and it works. ^_^

Comment: Yes, I thought I will delete the answer because of the duplicate, but I cannot delete an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong, `a(1,1:2)` is not a 2D array (which you call a matrix), it is a **1D array**.

Bu using `a(1,..` you are selecting a definite "row" in the "matrix" from which you take a "row vector" `1:2)`.

You must use

`a(1:1,1:2)`

for a 2D array of shape 1x2 (matrix with one line and two columns if you want).

Comment: I will leave this here long enough for the OP to read the explanation directly about his code.

Comment: What's the difference between `real a(3)` vs `real b(1,3)`? What's the syntax of 2D Array constructor like `a = [1,2,3]`? @VladimirF

Comment: `a(3)` is a 1D array of length 3, `b(1,3)` is a 2D array 1x3. There is no 2D array constructor, you can use `reshape()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708307/how-to-initialize-two-dimensional-arrays-in-fortran

Comment: Aha, thanks @VladimirF. I am really going through a hard time because of FORTRAN. Coming from a high-level language to FORTRAN is really pathetic.

Comment: It hasn't been called FORTRAN for more than 30 years. It is Fortran. And it is a high-level language (unlike assembly).